# How to localize text based on criterion other than language

Tags: ios, localization

I have an application which will be marketed in different European countries.  We've gone through the process of localizing the application so that its strings are maintained in the language-specific .lproj files in the Settings.bundle. This all works fine. The problem is that there are some strings which don't key off language, but off the country where the app is run.  For example, there are strings which differ between the Austrian version of the app and the German version of the app, even though both these countries speak German.  When it's run for the first time, the app asks the user which country it's running in.

Is there a way in which I can maintain these country-specific strings in a resource file, and have the resource file used at run time be decided by a user setting, in this case the country where the app is running, rather than the device language?

Thanks,

Peter Hornby

Comment: Peter, may I ask how you finally solved this problem? I'm facing the same problem right now. thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1):

Define two bundles on a singleton, fallback and preferred...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Localization : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* fallbackCountry;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* preferredCountry;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary* fallbackCountryBundle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary* preferredCountryBundle;

+(Localization *)sharedInstance;
- (NSString*) countryStringForKey:(NSString*)key;

@end


#import "Localization.h"

@implementation Localization

@synthesize fallbackCountryBundle, preferredCountryBundle;
@synthesize fallbackCountry, preferredCountry;

+(Localization *)sharedInstance 
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static Localization *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[Localization alloc] init];

        [shared setFallbackCountry:@"country-ES"];

        NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
        NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
        [shared setPreferredCountry:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"country-%@",countryCode]];
    });
    return shared;
}


-(void) setFallbackCountry:(NSString*)country
{
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:country ofType:@"strings"];
    self.fallbackCountryBundle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath];
    trace(@"Fallback: %@ %@",[bundlePath lastPathComponent], self.fallbackCountryBundle);
}


-(void) setPreferredCountry:(NSString*)country 
{
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:country ofType:@"strings"];
    self.preferredCountryBundle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath];

    BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:bundlePath isDirectory:nil];
    if (!exists) warn(@"%@.strings %@", country, exists ? @"FOUND" : @"NOT FOUND");

    trace(@"Preferred: %@ %@",[bundlePath lastPathComponent], self.preferredCountryBundle);
}


- (NSString*) countryStringForKey:(NSString*)key 
{
    NSString* result = nil;
    if (preferredCountryBundle!=nil) result = [preferredCountryBundle objectForKey:key];
    if (result == nil) result = [fallbackCountryBundle objectForKey:key];
    if (result == nil) result = key;

    return result;
}


@end
```

Then call it from a macro function

```
#define countryString(key) [[Localization sharedInstance]countryStringForKey:key];
```

Write a default file for ES, and one file per supported language. eg:

```
/* 
  country-ES.strings
*/

"hello" = "hello";
```

And just get the value for the key:

```
countryString(@"hello");
```

Comment: Thanks, Jano, this looks good.  I'm going to play with it and see if it does exactly what I need.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: I think the difficulty I had, and am still having, is that it seems to be impossible to arrange for strings in application settings accessed and managed through the device Settings application to be localized based on a criterion other than language.  If that's true, then I think my application must do what others seem to do, which is to bring the localization into the application itself, and have an "Info" button on the title bar which accesses these strings.  Since this is under full application control, I can do what I want as far as localization is concerned.  Do I have this right?

Comment: I wrote an example: https://github.com/j4n0/Blah It localizes based in the country you set in Settings > International > Region Format, and defaults to spanish if it doesn't find the file or key. If you want a different country for your app, you need a menu inside your app to call setPreferredCountry:.

Comment: Thanks, Jano.  The sample is instructive. I appreciate you taking the trouble to share it.

Comment: Jano, I know this is an old topic and things have changed but I really would have liked to see the project instead of a dead link.