# Dont want to restart the app when changing language

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use this line of code to change the language in my app

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
        setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", @"fr", nil]      
        forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Changes won't take place before the user restarts the app.
Do the user really need to restart the app before the changes will take place,
or is it possible to just reload the view controllers in some way to make the app change its language immediately.

Comment: NO need you can check condition where is settings change     [ GetLangKey:@"en"];

Comment: I gave up on NSLocalizedString and use my own code. It's simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163839/how-to-localize-text-based-on-criterion-other-than-language/7164302#7164302

Comment: Hmm, to bad, maybe changes to this has been done in iOS5.

Comment: @Flatron : Did you try to dismiss your current viewController when changing language, going back, release it really, then reload it ? If that works, then you could do that, AND in viewWillAppear in each ViewController, do the same thing. viewWillAppear is called each time a view appears, not depending if it comes to the screen, or if it it shown when another screen is dismissed. Does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
write below method in your appDelegate class
+(void)GetLangKey:(NSString *)Langkey
{
    NSString *tmpstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"LanguageResources" ofType:@"bundle"]]; 
    tmpstr =[tmpstr stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    tmpstr=[tmpstr stringByAppendingString:Langkey];
    tmpstr =[tmpstr stringByAppendingString:@".lproj"];

    //  NSLog(@"%@",tmpstr);
    myLocalizedBundle=[NSBundle bundleWithPath:tmpstr];
}
and call this method when your language  change
if([language isEqualToString:@"English"])
{
[app_obj GetLangKey:@"en"];
} 
else
{
 [app_obj GetLangKey:@"fr"];
}
```

Comment: That wont help me, I have .xib files that are localized to.